# How to Set Block Insert Size Parameters in Teradata

Tags: odbc, stata, teradata

I am using [odbc insert](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/dodbc.pdf) command in the statistics package Stata (v14.2) on an Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS server to insert some data into a Teradata DB (v14.10).

This Stata command has a `block` option, which makes Stata send the data in blocks of 1000 rows. Unfortunately the ODBC driver appears to be doing single-row inserts (according to the DBA who monitors the system).

Is it possible to alter the ODBC driver behavior?

If so, how does one specify the block size for the ODBC driver to use in the .odbc.ini file or a connection string?

I've looked the TD ODBC manual and Googled, but I could not find anything useful.

Comment: Teradata's ODBC driver supports parameter arrays (http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/db_ttu_14_00/index.html#page/Connectivity/B035_2509_071A/2509ch04.06.55.html), don't know if Stata can utilize it.

Comment: @dnoeth Do you know what I would need to alter in .odbc.ini or in the connection string?

Comment: No, sorry. I assume this would be a setting in Stata because the client needs to provide those arrays.

Comment: for python library there is batch=true Parametr https://github.com/Teradata/PyTd/issues/4 check if it helps

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @PearlySpencer Unfortunately not.

Comment: Is this a Stata issue or a more general ODBC driver problem?

Comment: I am not sure. I don't think remember if I tried other software with ODBC. I no longer work with Teradata, so I don't even have a way of testing this.